# How to make an exit method that doesn't repeat the entry twice?

Tags: java, methods

My problem here is, I need to make an exit method, a conversion method and an entry method. The problem is that I don't know to make an exit method that has both entry and conversion method values without the entry repeating twice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimeConverter{

   public static void main (String[]args){
      System.out.println ("This program converts minutes to seconds.");
      exit ();  
   }

   public static int entry (){
      System.out.print ("\nType in the amount of minutes:");
      Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
      int minutes = s.nextInt ();
      return minutes;
   }

   public static int Conversion (){
      int val1 = entry(),
          cont = val1 * 60;
      return cont;
   }

   public static void exit (){
      int seconds = conversion (),
          minutes = entry();
      System.out.print ("\n\n" + minutes + " is equal to " + seconds + " seconds.");
   }    
}
```

Comment: What's `Saida`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Saida was a mistake, my code is in portuguese so i translated it but saida wasn't translated yet.

Joe C My question is how to make a code with a conversion, entry and exit method that is close to this but doesn't repeat the entry twice. I know the reason why it repeats but i don't know how to make a code with these 3 methods that don't.

Answer (score 1):

I would construct the `Scanner` in `main`, and pass it to `entry`. Next, I would return the number of minutes from `entry` and pass that as an argument to the `conversion` method. Finally, pass `minutes` and `seconds` to `exit`. Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This program converts minutes to seconds.");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minutes = entry(s);
    int seconds = conversion(minutes);
    exit(minutes, seconds);
}

public static int entry(Scanner s) {
    System.out.println("Type a number of minutes:");
    return s.nextInt();
}

public static int conversion(int minutes) {
    return minutes * 60;
    // Java also has built-in helpers for this, and you could use
    // return (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);
}

public static void exit(int minutes, int seconds) {
    System.out.printf("%d minutes is equal to %d seconds.%n", minutes, seconds);
}
```

Comment: So if i put a variable that is in the main method on the () i will make them show up on my other method?